# How to pass element from array to query

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I would like to know, how I want to write some code, which gives me the index of element found in database.

I have function like this:

```
def get_teachers_names(name, lastname):
    try:
        params = config()

        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        select_query = "SELECT id FROM lecturers WHERE name = %s AND lastname = %s"
        record_to_find = (name, lastname)

        cur.execute(select_query, record_to_find)
        records = list(cur)

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()

        return records

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
```

When I do something like:

```
index = database.get_teachers_names('Name1', 'Surname1')
```

I get index I want. But when I have a lists:

```
names = ('Name1', 'Name2')
surnames = ('Surname1', 'Surname2')
```

And I try to do the same with:

```
index = database.get_teachers_names(names[0], surnames[0]
```

I get [] as result. I also tried:

```
index = database.get_teachers_names(''.join(names[0], ''.join(surnames[0]))
```

But it also didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Those are tuples not lists. Unless you have a list of tuples you are not showing.  You are just using those tuples right?

Answer (score 0):

It works when you pass a simple strings as they will populate the query string correctly:

```
index = database.get_teachers_names('Name1', 'Surname1')
```

However when you pass a list it won't be parsed correctly as a string in:

```
"SELECT id FROM lecturers WHERE name = %s AND lastname = %s"
```

I think the best approach for you is to loop over the list and execute this for each entry:
cur.execute(select_query, record_to_find)

You can then append the results to a the records list.

Comment: They are not passing a list. They are passing an individual element of a list.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I misread the question. 
No idea what is causing this then.